# How to show $|S| = |S \times A|$, where $S$ is infinite and $A$ is finite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Exactly what the title says. I have a proof where at one point, I use the fact that two copies of $S$ can be put in bijection with $S$, but I don't know how I'd prove that.

For countable sets, I can construct an explicit bijection, so I thought about partitioning $S$ into countable sets. But how can I be sure such a partition exists? I can't just say "take a countable subset, then take a countable subset of the remaining set, etc". I can surject it into a countable set, but I don't think that helps me much.

Is there a trick to doing this? (Also, I use the Axiom of Choice elsewhere in the proof, so that's allowable)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518886/show-that-2s-s-for-all-infinite-sets

See Asaf's answer.

Comment: I know pretty much nothing about ordinals, unfortunately. :\ Is it any easier for the case where $S$ is a basis for $R$ as a vector space over $Q$? (_pretty_ sure that's the same cardinality as $R$, but again, I can't prove that yet)

Comment: I don't either, I just knew that this came up before and thought it might be useful to you.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to show to a friend that $R$ and $R \times R$ are isomorphic as groups, so I was hoping it wouldn't stray that far out of scope. Maybe I'll just hide it under a "it is known that"...

and +1 for Dylan.

Comment: I figured that's what you were going for. I assume the argument you wanted was that they're both $\Bbb Q$ vector spaces of the same cardinality, and therefore isomorphic as $\Bbb Q$ vector spaces, and therefore underlying additive groups?

Comment: Yep. I've got the "same dimension (and field) implies isomorphic" part, and "R has a basis in Q" we did at PROMYS. So this is the only bit I'm missing now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the axiom of choice to prove this result in it generality. You can use several of its equivalents, of course, and it depends which one you are the most comfotable with.

You mentioned that you don't know much about ordinals and well-orders. So let us take another approach.

First of all, note that it suffices to prove that for $A=\{0,1\}$. If $A$ has more elements then one can proceed by induction by breaking $A$ into smaller parts and using the induction hypothesis and the case above.

So now to prove that $S\times\{0,1\}$ and $S$ have the same cardinality. Let us use Zorn's lemma and prove the following thing:

> There exists a partition of $S$ that each part has size $\aleph_0$.

Why would that be helpful? If we write $S=\bigcup S_i$, where $S_i$ is our partition into countably infinite parts, then $S\times\{0,1\}=\bigcup S_i\times\{0,1\}$. Using the axiom of choice the result is simple now, and I will leave it to you to finish the proof on your own.

So let us prove the main cake: the existence of this partition. Using Zorn's lemma we need to come up with a partial order that every chain has an upper bound, and then argue that the maximal element must have the wanted properties.

Let $P$ be the set of all partitions into $\aleph_0$-sized parts of a subset of $S$, and let us order them by $\subseteq$. Since $S$ is infinite, and the axiom of choice holds, it has a countably infinite subset which has an obvious partition. So now $P$ is non-empty, and let $C$ be a chain in $P$, it is easy to check that $T=\bigcup C$ is a partition of a subset of $S$, and each of its parts have size $\aleph_0$.

We can conclude, if so, that by Zorn's lemma there is a maximal element, $T$. By definition $T$ is a partition of a subset of $S$, let $S'=\bigcup T$, then $S\setminus S'$ cannot be infinite, or else we can add another infinite part to $T$ and contradict its maximality. Therefore it must be finite, if it is empty we are done, otherwise just pick one $S_i\in T$ and replace it by $S_i\cup(S\setminus S')$ which is a countably infinite set as wanted.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: Henry, if this is for proving that $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ are isomorphic as additive groups, then you need vastly less than that.

Comment: How so? Does it involve showing that $|\mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{R} \times \{0, 1\}|$, specifically?

Comment: @Henry: Yes, but that much is provable without the axiom of choice. $$|\Bbb R|=|\Bbb{N^N}|=|\Bbb{N^{N\times2}}|=|(\Bbb{N^N})^2|=|\Bbb R^2|,$$ then you just have to show that if $\Bbb R$ has a basis then it has cardinality $\Bbb R$, but that much is not hard. Using the axiom of choice to do so, one can easily analyze and see that the cardinal arithmetic used for this is pretty much provable without any choice (as the product above). So the only part requiring choice is the existence of a Hamel basis.

Answer (score 2):

Enumerate $S = \{ s_{\alpha} : \alpha < \lambda \}$ and $A = \{ a_i : i < n \}$. Define a map $S \times A \to S$ by
$$(s_{\alpha}, a_i) \mapsto s_{\alpha \cdot n + i}$$
Check that this is an injection, and deduce the result.

Comment: It seems I should learn more (anything) about ordinals.

Comment: @HenrySwanson: That's probably a good idea if you want to start reasoning about infinite sets! There is likely to be a way of doing this without using ordinals, but I can't think of one right now. (Also, my answer used the axiom of choice, and I feel like this should be true without it.)

Comment: Clive, it is true for well-orderable sets without the axiom of choice. The axiom of choice simply gives us the fact that every set is well-orderable.